# how to determine the pinouts of a 6 pin optical slot sensor/encoder?

Tags: encoder

i have a 6 pin optical slot sensor/optical encoder, which does not have a part # on it. I need a way to determine what each pin is. I will award the answer to the first answer that accurately explains the process of determining the function of each pin. thanks!

Comment: The process of determining the function of each pin is to obtain and study the datasheet for the device you wish to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you have no markings to be able to obtain a spec-sheet for the device. If you do this is a non-starter.

If not, you need to look at it mechanically first.

One side will likely be an LED the other with have either two photo-diodes or photo-transistors.

Once you identify the LED side you can attach the other side pins through a resistor in combinations and polarities or all pairs to a low voltage supply and see what happens when you turn the LED on and off.

Chart out that information and you should be able to identify the "truth-table" of the device.

If you can't identify the LED, repeat the last step for all pins. That is apply low power through 2 (say 5ma), measure the others, reverse, try the next two.. etc.

Comment: the encoder is mounted on a pcb which is mounted on a motor. i do not have full mechanical access, only can see one side (4 pin side) and have access to all the pins.

Comment: @parzival then go with the latter part. There are a lot of permutations but patience will prevail.

Comment: should i assume the led has a 2v drop, and needs 20 milliamps, or is that a dangerous(for the led) assumption?

Comment: @parzival yes 1.5-2V would be typical, but I'd limit to 5mA. That should be plenty to notice a change elsewhere with like a 10K series on the test side.

Comment: also, would the photo-diodes or photo-transistors have polarity?

Comment: @parzival yes they will. The numbers you get should tell you which is which.

Comment: i should put a resistor on the leds and on the sensor side? 10kohms?=

Comment: @parzival note detector side may be separate diodes or +- supply and two outputs. Or the whole thing could be smart.. then it gets harder to understand,.

Comment: @parzival 10K will be fine, with like 5V supply.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71160/discussion-between-parzival-and-trevor).